Restrict Movement of turtles
I am working with a data set (raster type) importing into Netlogo. I must make sure that the birds (in this case the type 2 bird) do not leave the imported area (because they are moving both outside it and inside it).I had stipulated the movement of the bird in the following way:
However, I would like Ask if there is a simpler way? Or is the way I'm handling it okay?
to move-aves2 
  pen-down 
let target one-of patches with [pcolor = 8 or pcolor = 68 or pcolor = 79 or pcolor = 49 or pcolor = 28 ]
  if target != nobody [ face target
    fd 8 
     set energy energy - 17.19 ] 

 if any? patches in-radius 10 with [borde-negro = 1] [
  let black-patches patches with [pcolor = 130]
  let safe-patches patches with [pcolor != 130]
  let target-patch min-one-of safe-patches [distance myself]
  ifelse any? black-patches in-radius 10 [
      face min-one-of black-patches [distance myself]
      lt 180 
    fd 1  
  ] [
    face target-patch 
    fd 9
  ]
]

An advice to my question because although the code works I don't know if I did it correctly

One improvement is to use global variables instead of local variables for patches with [pcolor = 8 or pcolor = 68 or pcolor = 79 or pcolor = 49 or pcolor = 28 ] and black-patches and safe-patches. That will make your code a little simpler and (probably) much faster to execute.
If patch colors never change, do this in setup:
set colored-patches patches with [pcolor = 8 or pcolor = 68 or ...
set black-patches patches with [pcolor = 130]
set safe-patches patches with [pcolor != 130]

If patch colors do change, just repeat those set statements.
